# How to read the text contents of a paragraph tag in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, hide

This part of code hides the paragraph when clicked upon:

```
$("body").on("click", "p", function() {          
    $(this).hide();                           
});
```

The paragraph only contains text and they are stored in the localstorage with the name "name". So, if the content is "sometext" then it is stored in using the code `localstorage["sometext"]="sometext"`. I want to remove that para from my local storage when it is clicked. For that I need the text of the para that was clicked.

Comment: why not `localStorage.removeItem('sometext')`

Answer (score 1):

To get the text of the para, you can use the `text()` method. Try this:

```
$('p').click(function () {
  var textOfPara = $(this).text();
  /* if depending on it then */
  if(textOfPara == 'sometext') {
    // remove the element using localStorage.removeItem('parameter');
  }
}
```